# Newtonsoft.Json randomly not loading in NopCommerce

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, json.net

Up until yesterday we only saw this error once before when the site first went live but now it has happened two days consecutively.

This is the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

So far, what seems to work is toggling the ClassLibrary > References > Newtonsoft.Json > "Copy Local" property (between True and False), then pushing the appropriate .dll's up.

Does anyone know why this references randomly becomes inaccessible?

I'm a .Net and NopCommerce noob so any advice or articles that would shed some light or point me in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: How many projects do you have in the solution?
And do they need newtonsoft.json or not?